# Flutter: Custom Markers, image icon from url

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I am trying to add image icon from the URL.

```
  var _userProfilePic = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(),
      Image.network(_userPrimaryInfo['user_profile_picture_url']),
      );

      Set<Marker> _userLocation = {
        Marker(
          markerId: _userPrimaryInfo['user_id'],
          position: LatLng(
              32,
              124),
          icon: _userProfilePic,
        )
      };
```

This is what I have so far. And, it is not working. Getting `The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dartargument_type_not_assignable` this error.

How can I add image icon from url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you, first Convert image to Unit8List

```
Future < Uint8List > getBytesFromCanvas(int width, int height, urlAsset) async 
{
    final ui.PictureRecorder pictureRecorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    final Canvas canvas = Canvas(pictureRecorder);
    final Paint paint = Paint()..color = Colors.transparent;
    final Radius radius = Radius.circular(20.0);
    canvas.drawRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
            Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, width.toDouble(), height.toDouble()),
            topLeft: radius,
            topRight: radius,
            bottomLeft: radius,
            bottomRight: radius,
        ),
        paint);

    final ByteData datai = await rootBundle.load(urlAsset);

    var imaged = await loadImage(new Uint8List.view(datai.buffer));

    canvas.drawImage(imaged, new Offset(0, 0), new Paint());

    final img = await pictureRecorder.endRecording().toImage(width, height);
    final data = await img.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    return data.buffer.asUint8List();
}

Future < ui.Image > loadImage(List < int > img) async {
    final Completer < ui.Image > completer = new Completer();
    ui.decodeImageFromList(img, (ui.Image img) {

        return completer.complete(img);
    });
    return completer.future;
}
```

> Then use like this

```
final Uint8List markerIcond = await getBytesFromCanvas(80, 98, urlAsset);

setState(() {

    markersMap[markerId] = Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId("marker_${id}"),
        position: LatLng(double.parse(place.lat), double.parse(place.lng)),

        icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(markerIcond),
        onTap: () {
            _onMarkerTapped(placeRemote);
        },

    );
});
```